# Movement not working in c++ console game ( using _kbhit and _getch )

Tags: c++, 2d, 2d-games

Im using an two dimensional array for coordinates. Creating and display board with random coordinates for the goal is working. But, movement is not working (it is w,a,s,d). Im using the functions `_kbhit` and `_getch` for movement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

bool gameOver = false;
char board[10][10];
int goalX, goalY, playerX, playerY, score;
enum eDirection
{
    STOP = 0, LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN
};
eDirection direction;

void Setup();
void Show(int playerX, int playerY, int goalX, int goalY, enum eDirection);
void Input(int playerX, int playerY, int goalX, int goalY, enum eDirection);
void Logic(int playerX,
           int playerY,
           int goalX,
           int goalY,
           enum eDirection,
           int score);

int main()
{
    Setup();

    while (!gameOver)
    {
        system("cls");
        Show(playerX, playerY, goalX, goalY, direction);
        Input(playerX, playerY, goalX, goalY, direction);
        Logic(playerX, playerY, goalX, goalY, direction, score);
    }
}

void Setup()
{
    direction = STOP;
    score = 0;
    playerX = 5;
    playerY = 5;

    srand(time(NULL));
    goalX = rand() % 10;
    goalY = rand() % 10;

}

void Show(int playerX, int playerY, int goalX, int goalY, enum eDirection)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = '*';
            board[playerX][playerY] = 'P';
            board[goalX][goalY] = 'G';
            cout << board[i][j];

        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void Input(int playerX, int playerY, int goalX, int goalY, enum eDirection)
{
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        switch (_getch())
        {
            case 'w':
                direction = UP;
                break;
            case 'a':
                direction = LEFT;
                break;
            case 's':
                direction = DOWN;
                break;
            case 'd':
                direction = RIGHT;
                break;
        }
    }
}

void Logic(int playerX,
           int playerY,
           int goalX,
           int goalY,
           enum eDirection,
           int score)
{
    switch (direction)
    {
        case UP:
            playerY++;
            break;
        case LEFT:
            playerX--;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            playerY--;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            playerX++;
            break;
    }

    if (playerX == goalX && playerY == goalY)
    {
        score += 10;
        goalX = rand() % 10;
        goalY = rand() % 10;
    }

}
```

Comment: That is the most C like C++ I have seen in a while.  No classes, all C calls except cout.  Consider switching to C or using C++ for everything :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Haha, I tried to make it pretty simple to just practice using arrays and make stuff move, before I make a big project.

Comment: Also should really check to be sure player stays on board.  Any reason to use kbhit() at all?  Can you not block and just wait for input with your getch() function?  As it is now, if it works, you would hit a direction and then fly at lightspeed through memory until you crash (no delay on loop, so same input from last loop used.  No edge detction so weeee through memory.)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Yeah I might make some if commands to make sure the player is on the board, but for now just trying to see why my player isnt moving.                                              Edit: Can I use a sleep command from <windows.h> for delay?

Comment: Why pass is `eDirection` to `Input` just to ignore and use the global `direction` directly?  Same for all functions.  Pass the value, or pass the reference and modify the value.  I think that is a root of a lot of your issues.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Oh haha, didnt notice that, should probably remove that. Any other ideas on why its not working?

Comment: Update your code with fixes and then pull out a debugger and see why the input isn't being processed.  Without moving this to my local system and running it (no time today), I can't take this much further.